# High memory usage EE3.5.3

Tags: control-panel, memory-limit

We're getting a Fatal Error when creating a new entry or update anything in the control panel.
*Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/cp/ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php on line 118*

Memory limit is set to 256 and should be enough. We've got a couple of modules like Structure, Publisher Lite, Bloqs, CE Cache and a couple more.
There are about 750 entries.

We could increase the memory but it seems a bit much. Is this normal memory usage for an Expression Engine install?

Answer (score 1):

Structure keeps a history log and took up to 12000 records in the database. Cleared the records and things went back to normal. Updated Structure and should not happen anymore.
https://eeharbor.com/structure/changelog#entry-6